# HtmlUnit: Determine file size

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am downloading a file from the web via HtmlUnit.
This is what my (working) code looks like:

```
Page dlPage = client.getPage(url);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
try
{
  IOUtils.copy(dlPage.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream(), fos);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
  fos.close();
}
```

I want to show the download progress. Therefore I need to know the file size. The Content-Length header is sent by the server but the problem is that I can read the headers after the file is downloaded. the `getPage()` method is blocking until the file is downloaded.

Is there any way to read just the response headers first in HtmlUnit and then the content? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use **getContentLength()** method of **URLConnection** to get the length when the connection is established.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is that ``dlPage.getWebResponse().getContentLength()`` returns the content length after the content is downloaded.

Comment: Yup. That's because Page downloads the page-content when instantiated.
That's why I mentioned getContentLength method of URL CONNECTION.

Create a connection to the same url using URLConnection and fetch the content length through that.
It would remotely fetch the content length and the headers (if needed).

Comment: How do I get a UrlConnection in my example? I posted an answer with a way I just tried and it worked. is this what you meant?

Comment: URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.getContentLength();

This is how you can do this.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean. The problem is that I need to be logged in on the page. This is why I need HtmlUnit in order to fill the login form and authenticate. With the plain java solution this is not working. But it would be a nicer solution for websites that don't require a login.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out a way to get this working: Before the download I send a HEAD request to the server so I can use the response to read the content length:

```
WebRequest wr = new WebRequest(new URL(url), HttpMethod.HEAD);
Page wrPage = client.getPage(wr);
long contentLength = Integer.valueOf(wrPage.getWebResponse().getResponseHeaderValue("Content-Length"));
System.out.println(contentLength);
```

Comment: Please note - this will work if the response is static content. In case of dynamic content - server code should handle "head" request and there should be a way to quickly calculate the content size. In most of the cases only way to calculate content size is generating the whole page content. Therefore use with caution. It will affect the result if you are using HTMLUnit as part of a load testing script.